# Syntax Error in From clause ms access

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, ms-access

I am trying to query data from Ms access database with the following code.

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO Mre_Pole (ElementID,GlobalID,UpdateState) values (:ElementID,:GlobalID,:UpdateState)";
string commandText2 = @"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Mre_Pole ORDER BY objectid DESC";
command.CommandText = sql;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":ElementID", entityGuid.EntityId);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":GlobalID", entityGuid.Guid);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":UpdateState", UpdateState.Added);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.Parameters.Clear();
command.CommandText = commandText2;

OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
```

but it throws an exception `dataAdapter.Fill(ds);`

> Syntax Error in From clause

Anyone please help me with this problem.

Comment: You should probably remove the `:` and please note that access do not support named parameters. It's common to just use `?` like the example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't see anything wrong as a syntax in your `SELECT` statement. Are you sure your `CommandText` is `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Mre_Pole ORDER BY objectid DESC`? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: what the messagebox is showing?

Answer (score 0):

Try

Change

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
```

to

```
 OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(commandText2,"your oledbconnection");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
```